# gcloud run deploy ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Invalid value for [source]: Dockerfile required when specifying --tag

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, dockerfile, nestjs, gcloud

I was trying to deploy to CloudRun for the first time by following instruction on a blog (By Tom Ray : [Deploying a NestJS app to Cloud Run with Github Actions](https://www.tomray.dev/deploy-nestjs-cloud-run)).

In the section "Use gcloud run deploy", when giving the command `gcloud run deploy` I got this unclear error message:

```
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Invalid value for [source]: Dockerfile required when specifying --tag
```

Answer (score 2):

Searching the web I could not find an answer or hint to explain the error message.

After moving on to another tutorial I understood what my mistake was.

It was a simple "case sensitive" syntax error naming of the docker file.

I named it "dockerfile" and it should have been named "Dockerfile".

This is a unique naming convention from all the other filenames in the project, they are either all lowercase or all uppercase.

A better error message would have been "ERROR: Missing Dockerfile", that would have been enough for me to find the cause.

[image]